# Why won't a div go inside another div?

Tags: html, css

hope you're well and you can lend a hand. Just another one of those small hurdles to overcome with this coding malarkey.

I don't understand how I cant get the 'jobs' div inside the big blue div, just like the 'experience' one. It doesn't add up, I've just confused myself by trying to work it out for too long now!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZzpzj?editors=1100#0

Any help appreciated.

```
div.experiencebox {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background-color: blue;
}

div.experiencetitle {
width: 49%;
background: green;
min-height: auto;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
vertical-align: top;
}

div.jobs {
width: 49%;
background: green;
min-height: auto;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: You have unclosed tags in your `HTML`. Try to use anything that highlights your coding syntax errors. Either an IDE or an online tool. This is one of the many reasons I prefer jsfiddle to codepen.

Comment: thank you, jsfiddle it is. bit of a newb question, but gota start somewhere! cheers for the help

Comment: No online snippet tool stands a chance before any decent IDE. And it will probably be like this for a while. Even free ones. My personal choice is irrelevant, but if you are serious about web development, that should be your next step. Choosing and using an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

you're missing a >

in

```
<div class="experiencetitle"
```

so

```
<div class="experiencetitle">
```

.......

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not nested properly and you have some syntax errors. See this fork for a working example: http://codepen.io/azizn/pen/VedQMw

```
<div class="experiencebox">
  <div class="experiencetitle">
    <div class="experiencetext">
      <p>Experience </br>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/benjamin-robinson-158a06113">Read more on LinkedIn</a> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="jobs">
      <p>Jobs</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the speedy speedy reply. can you explain where i went wrong briefly please. be valuable so i know for next time

Comment: You had a missing ">" a div should be opened and closed properly, syntax errors are the leading cause of display problems so please be careful. you can use tools to validate the HTML and check for errors